# .htaccess File Security

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is this .htaccess file safe? Saw it as default in my web host's root folder

```
# -FrontPage-

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName mydomain.com
AuthUserFile /home/myname/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home/myname/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp
```

**php_flag register_globals off ---BTW throws 500 internal on server**

///This doesn't work

///Rewrite and remove .php extension

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Please any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is safe. Touch it only if you know what you are doing.

Comment: But where do I place my rewrite instructions and stuff?

Comment: @Frank: Underneath the other lines.

Comment: Throwing 500 Internal Server Error....but the same .htaccess file works on local server